Deploying Carbon Application with "Required features are not installed in the system" issue
I have deploy issue.
Could someone take a look? Any ideas?
Thanks.
[2024-09-16 10:55:06,773]  INFO - ApplicationManager Deploying Carbon Application : IntProjectExporter_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.car...
[2024-09-16 10:55:06,781]  WARN - SynapseAppDeployer Can't deploy artifact : GetUsers of type : synapse/endpoint. Required features are not installed in the system
[2024-09-16 10:55:06,781]  WARN - SynapseAppDeployer Can't deploy artifact : GetUsers of type : synapse/endpoint. Required features are not installed in the system
[2024-09-16 10:55:06,781]  WARN - SynapseAppDeployer Can't deploy artifact : GetUsers of type : synapse/endpoint. Required features are not installed in the system
[2024-09-16 10:55:06,782]  INFO - API {api:Sample:v1.0.0} Initializing API: Sample:v1.0.0
[2024-09-16 10:55:06,782]  INFO - DependencyTracker API : Sample:v1.0.0 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully - [ Deployed From Artifact Container: IntProjectExporter ]
[2024-09-16 10:55:06,782]  INFO - APIDeployer API named 'Sample:v1.0.0' has been deployed from file : /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-4.3.0/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1726484106773IntProjectExporter_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.car/Sample_1.0.0_1.0.0/Sample_1.0.0-1.0.0.xml
[2024-09-16 10:55:06,783]  INFO - ApplicationManager Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : IntProjectExporter_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT {super-tenant}

looks like you have some component installed localy but not on the prod server. compare the installed components...
